# MySQL - Unknown column '125X' in 'where clause', weird error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am having a weird MySQL behavior. I am updating mutliple rows at once with queries like this:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET field1= CASE numbertofind
    WHEN 1234 THEN 'voltron'
    WHEN 1598 THEN 'optimus Prime'
    WHEN 4444 THEN 'redbonzai'
    WHEN 125X THEN 'PHP'
END,
field2= CASE numbertofind
    WHEN '1234' THEN 'Bozo'
    WHEN '1598' THEN 'transformer'
    WHEN '4444' THEN 'Teddy Bear'
    WHEN '125X' THEN 'Linux'
END
WHERE fieldValue2 IN ('1234', '1598', '4444', '125X');
```

It all works fine as long as i only have numbers in the WHEN clause. For example, "WHEN 125X" gives me this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column '125X' in 'where clauses'
```

The column exists of course. The "numbertofind" field is of type varchar in my database.
I really have no clue what causes this error, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a `single quete` as 125x its a **string** not **number** ,else mysql will treat it as number 
or as column name(If it does not look like a number)

```
WHEN '125X' THEN 'PHP'
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `MySql` is handling that `125X` as a column name since it is not parsed as a string.

The example for `field1` the search for:

```
WHEN 125X THEN 'PHP'
```

should be wrapped in quotes as you do for `field2`:

```
WHEN '125X' THEN 'PHP'
```

so the engine knows you are trying to compare the `string` `125X` to the varchar column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put strings in quotes. When a value isn't quoted, it's treated as a number if it looks like a number, otherwise it's treated as a column name (or you get a syntax error if it's not valid syntax for a column name). So your `CASE` statement for `field1` should be like the one for `field2`, with all the `WHEN` values being quoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHEN '125X' THEN 'PHP'
```

Or:

```
WHEN "125X" THEN 'PHP'
```

As you did for:

```
WHEN '125X' THEN 'Linux'
```

From [control flow functions:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

> The return type of a CASE expression is the compatible aggregated type
>   of all return values, but also depends on the context in which it is
>   used. If used in a string context, the result is returned as a string.
>   If used in a numeric context, the result is returned as a decimal,
>   real, or integer value.